# How to stop filevault to compress jcr hierarchy?

Tags: aem, jcr, crx, filevault

I am working on cq and crx server. When I make package using package manager there (which uses filevault), I see that it is compressing some of hierarchy.

For example, suppose there is a hierarchy `/apps/a/b/c/d` and when I try to make its package. I get folders `apps`, inside that I get folder `a` but inside that, there is only a file `.content.xml`, in this xml file, contents of folders b, c and d are described using xml tags. The nodes b,c and d are of type `nt:unstructured`

I want to get exact hierarchy in file system as there is jcr hierarchy in crx server.

Answer (score 0):

The serialized output will depend on the node type. Filevault doesn't serialize every internal node as a folder. There are 4 different ways in which the nodes may be serialized. The case where the entire sub tree is serialized into a single file is called [Full Coverage Aggregate](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/filevault/vaultfs.html#Full_coverage_aggregates).

Comment: Is there a way to get same hierarchy of folders instead of getting serialized output?

Comment: @RahulJain can you add the use case you are targeting for this

Comment: The nodes that are getting serialized within one xml file are all `nt:unstructured` type. Is there any way to get each of them as a folder instead?